# getting a stringArray resource with a string variable

Tags: android

I am trying to get a stringArray resource with this code:

```
String continent = "europe";  
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continent);
```

If I type R.array.europe, its ok, but I want this to be dynamic, so I'm looking for a way to use my string variable here..

This is probably a simple java problem, but I'm quite a noob both in java and android programming, and I didn't find the answer..

Thanks in advance;

edit: so here is my complete onCreate Method, did I do something wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
       String continent = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getString("continent");

       int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier(continent, "Array",
               this.getPackageName());

       String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                items));

    }
```

I'm not sure about the defPackage part though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the name of the resource created dynamically in code, you could look at using

```
getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage);
```

This will return an id for a specified resource.

Comment: thank you very much, it looks like what I need, I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `String` variable containing "R.array." and append it with your `continent` object.

Comment: but my continent object is a string, putting R.array.europe as a string will not do... i need to be able to get the resource from a string...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. From what you said in your question, it sounds like continent is dynamic, so you want to pull the string resource based on continent. So if you append "R.array." with whichever continent is selected, you should get "R.array.selectedContinent" as your result.

Comment: exactly, but that gives me a string, and the getStringArray method seems to be looking for an integer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Using

getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage);

with

**name** : should be the resource name inside the file. ( Avoid adding R.array. in the begining of your resource name, because there is no resource with name R.array.yourname )
**deftype**: Should be "array".
**defPackage**: this.getPackageName()

The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach that I find easy to use:

`int resourceId = R.array.class.getField(yourStringVariable).getInt(null);`
`String[] yourStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);`

Note that yourStringVariable is in the form "europe", not "R.array.europe".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array resource id using this :

```
Sting name = "resource_array_name";
int resourceId= getResources().getIdentifier(name, "array",this.getPackageName());
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
```